# Why does this error happen in Oracle APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I constantly get this "*fieldname* must have some value" error and I don't understand why it happens because I **do** enter all the values into the respective fields.

pic:

[image]

Comment: Dropdown lists have a display and return value. Maybe this entry was configured with a display value but has a null return value

Answer (score 0):

I presume that

- items' "Value required" property is set to YES, and/or
- there's a validation (automatically created by Apex because table column is set to be NOT NULL)

So, try to change that (just to see what happens):

- set the "Value required" property to NO,
- set validation's "Condition" type to NEVER

Then run the page again. If table columns are set to be NOT NULL, you'll get the error again, but this time not from Apex, but from the database. Then you'll know that *something* really went wrong on your Apex page.

(BTW, as of *data zatrudnienia*: Michal is a male, is it not? In Croatian, that would be date when Michal got pregnant (?!?) :) )